# Get Google's authentication_token in the Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-client

I want to use the Google API in my Rails application. For this, I need to authenticate to a Google Dev account to get the `authentication_token`.

The best way to do it, in my opinion, is to use oauth2 library and examples provided in the documentation.

As you see, I have tried to use `Google::APIClient` in there, although I am stuck with the following issue below

In the console I get:

```
Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12('file.p12', 'notasecret')
NameError: uninitialized constant Google
```

I'm using following gems:

```
gem 'oauth2'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'google-api-client'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to require a file

```
require 'google/api_client/auth/key_utils'
```

Only then you would be allowed calling a `Google::APIClient::KeyUtils`.

You can notice in [the documentation](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) they require each class/module separately.

It seems like gem does not load all of its dependencies itself, because of their ideology and just not to overload the application with redundant libraries that won't be used.

Take a note, it is quite possible you will need to require some other libraries.